Webapp in blazor webassembly, alow to modify Json through Edge option Override content and pass the process
In a Webapp in blazor webassembly, the option on Edge navigator Devtools / "Override content" allow to modify the json file and pass the process.
Exemple :
I recieved from a call API a status {UserId : 12345 , Authorised: False }
With the option in DevTools Override content (right click on the json File) we can change the property Boolean to True and continue.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/javascript/overrides
How can i block this process...
Thanks for your help.
I have no Idea to block that

You can't. Browsers are not to be trusted. Always perform security checks on the API server. So even if they hack the ui, the server should repeat auth checks for sensitive apis so they never get sensitive data.
